# Efficient storage and retrieval of many location points for display in mapoverlay

Tags: java, android, sqlite, indexing

### Goal

Log signal strength on the current location of the android phone. And then display them all on a map.

### What is being stored

records of the form < longitude, latitude, value > in an sqlite database on android. I use ORMLite as an abstraction layer to store and retrieve data.

In the application I'm making (logging) it will create really a lot of points. In fact every 500 miliseconds I have to create a log entry

### What I do so far

I query for logpoints with longitude and latitude between ranges. But this is really inefficient O(n) (correct me if I'm wrong)

In the application I'm making (logging) it will

### My Question

What method of indexing should I use. Or do I have to take another approach?

Comment: Are you doing just data collection and/or display on mobile device as well? Also why a data point every 1/2 second as that will drain the battery.

Comment: I've suggested another time. But that is what my workgiver wants. I'll try to convince him. Anyway. yes display happens on mobile device as well. And all that works, only it works slow .. too slow

Comment: Maybe first i'll do some benchmarking on what is the slowest part. Retrieval or drawing. Because I just realised that drawing might make it very slow as well

Answer (score 0):

I've done something kind of similar. I was getting the users location every 5 minutes but when I was getting the location, I would capture the location every 500 milliseconds for 1 minute (I was doing this to try and get the most accurate location). The locations were stored in an in-memory list. After the minute was up, I sorted them by decreasing accuracy, took the first one in the list and discarded the rest. Then I retrieved the last location from my SQLLite database and compared the two locations - if the new location was the same as the previous location (within a tolerance of 50 metres), I discarded the new location; if not, it was committed to the database.
I did it this way to ensure I got the most accurate reading and to ensure I didn't have hundreds of locations to map, all on top of one another. Perhaps you could implement a similar 'filter' on location and/or signal strength.